# Increment in volt showing error

Tags: phalcon

```
{% set counter = 0 %}

{% for remain_todolist in remain_todolists %}

    {% if counter == countRem_todolist %}
        ['{{ remain_todolist.Project_Name }}', {{ remain_todolist.Remaining_Todos }}]
    {% else %}
        ['{{ remain_todolist.Project_Name }}', {{ remain_todolist.Remaining_Todos }}],
    {% endif %}~

    {% do counter++ %}//Showing Error

{% endfor %}
```

Volt Increment statement is showing error
"Unknown expression 279"

What i am doing wrong ?

Comment: Have you tried without the `do` keyword?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried without the `do` keyword?

Anyway, Volt loops already have counters available to use (see [Loop Context](http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/volt.html#loop-context)), here's a version using it:

```
{% for list in remain_todolists %}
    ['{{ list.Project_Name }}', {{ list.Remaining_Todos }}]{{ loop.last ? '' : ',' }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Ya i have tried without the 'do' but then also it was giving error. Thank you for the 'loop.last'. Worked like charm.

Answer (score 0):

As @cvsguimaraes suggest you can use Loop context which should be better in your case.

I don't think that `do` statement is valid in Volt. If you need counter value outside loop you can increment value just like that:

```
{% set counter = counter + 1 %}
```

Comment: It gives me 1 all the time ;)